# Execute powershell script in Java JSFrame

Tags: java, powershell, jframe

I have developed a demo app in JSFrame which should execute powershell script in my folder.

I am trying following code.

```
 private void jButton3ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
            // TODO add your handling code here:

            try
            {
            Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
            Process proc = runtime.exec("powershell C:\\helloworld.ps1");
            InputStream is = proc.getInputStream();
            InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(isr);
            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
            {
                System.out.println(line);
            }
            reader.close();
            proc.getOutputStream().close();
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
            }
        }
```

And in helloworld.ps1, I am having following command :

```
$strString = "Hello World 123"
write-host $strString
```

But I am not getting any output.

Comment: `Write-Host` => `Write-Output`

Comment: Code Execution stucks in while condition

Comment: Start by having a look at [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) for reasons why the UI won't update